# How to validate multiple phone number using regular expression

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, regex

I have a scenario, where i have to validate multiple phone numbers at a time. For example i will input phone number like this in the grid.

+46703897733;+46733457773;+46703443832;+42708513544;+91703213815;+919054400407.

Any one help me please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Javascript or C#? Make your mind up.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation

Comment: any specific pattern that you want to match?

Comment: Please post you code so far. Question must show an attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: In ASP.net, use inbuilt RegularExpressionValidator, you will find many frequently used validations written for you by MS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code for +46... numbers.
other number is simlar

```
 string regexPattern = @"^+46[0-9]{9}$";
    Regex r = new Regex(regexPattern);

    foreach(string s in numbers)
    {
        if (r.Match(s).Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Match");
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is very much hard-coded, how do you match with this expression all the numbers supplied by the OP?For every different code (+42, +91 etc) you need to write a separate Regex with this approach.

Comment: The code for this example.
For all cases, you can use this code   @"^+[1-9][0-9]{10}$"

Answer (score 0):

1. Choose appropriate and suitable regular expression e.g. from [here](http://regexlib.com/%28A%280NmPVPVWb9FcyjId4mQ0bF6Surg5rcH1x0bWJWs5GH8kE0uR-nNdxG_aH2T1a9Qr1UMSsCxTBnqqa7-LVeIH2CHKCtPnTGZNTzgINSadPfwZ0yOYsyi_96vbBqXP51znpVAKe-3btZULuVW8v5EnSDG0_0cPMtOHlkGo3EQ3bVO-DJsVep8i716Uzt7iVhzA0%29%29/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=6&categoryId=7)
2. Iterate through your number collection and validate them one by one like:

   ```
   Regex rgx = new Regex(yourPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
   foreach(string num in numbers)
   {
   if(rgx.Matches(num ))
   //do something you need
   }
   ```

   You also can add RegularExpressionValidator to your phone number column cells in grid and pass it your pattern. Then button click or any event that causes validation will do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

if **+** is mandatory in your number than do this in c#

```
        string[] numbers = new string[] { "+46703897733","+46733457773","46733457773"};
         string regexPattern = @"^\+(\d[\d-. ]+)?(\([\d-. ]+\))?[\d-. ]+\d$";
        Regex r = new Regex(regexPattern);

        foreach(string s in numbers)
        {
            if (r.Match(s).Success)
            {
               //"+46703897733","+46733457773" are valid in this case
                Console.WriteLine("Match");
            }
        }
```

if **+** is not mandatory you can do this

```
         string regexPattern = @"^\+?(\d[\d-. ]+)?(\([\d-. ]+\))?[\d-. ]+\d$";
         // all the numbers in the sample above will be considered as valid.
```

Comment: i have verified it. What is your input and the output you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression pattern should be then:

```
[+][1-9][0-9]*
```

and this is as of you required; If you want to limit it, like to: +911234567890, then your exp should be:

```
[+][1-9][0-9]{11,11}
```